# error while running latex code with embedded python code

Tags: python

I am trying to run python code within my latex code. i tried simple hellow world example but i have occured through this error . my latex file name is pyinlt.tex

Error:

```
i can't find file 'pyinlt.py.out'         
   <to be read again>
                \def
```

Source file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{python}
\begin{document}
Say hello Python:
\begin{python}
print r"Hello \LaTeX!"    
\end{python}        
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post the contents of the pyinlt.log file.

Comment: Try to compile it with `latex -shell-escape pyinlt.tex`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

`python` environnement requires some privilege that are disabled by default. The way to compile is to enable them by using `-shell-escape` at compilation time:

```
latex -shell-escape pyinlt.tex
```